# What is PortletURLListener used for? And can I make use of it in a hook?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

Can somebody give me a use case as to how can the `PortletURLListener` be used? if it can be used at all?

Like we have `ModelListener` can we also use `PortletURLListener`?

Just like in `ModelListener` we can inject functionality on creation of a model, on update of a model or on delete and so on.

1. So can we use the `PortletURLListener` the same way like `ModelListener` to do
   something when a specific URL is called? Any other approach if not `PortletURLListener`? Since the name is such I thought that could be of help.
2. And can we use it in a hook? or it is just used by Liferay? Any other practical usecase you have seen or implemented by extending or using this class?

Thanks in advance.

Thanks Mark for the prompt :-)

Answer (score 1):

The `PortletURLListener` is used e.g. for deploying and undeploying by Liferay core. For more details see Liferay sources for `PortletHotDeployListener`:

https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-impl/src/com/liferay/portal/deploy/hot/PortletHotDeployListener.java

Answer after Update:

You can create hook and put `servlet.service.events.post=com.my.MyAfterChangeAction` propery to the `portal.properties`. The MyAfterChangeAction class must implements `com.liferay.portal.kernel.events.Action`.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But I wanted to know why is it used? and how can we use it, if possible?

Comment: You have cool approach - looking for some classes and then ask - how can I use it :) What is your target, what do you want to reach?

Comment: I will try to edit my question and be a little more specific.

Comment: The correct approach is to look for JavaDoc. And in liferay there is none. So, here we are :)

Comment: Of course, this "none" can't stand without a polite reply: http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs/ - yes, it's not perfect and PortletURLListener is empty in there (so yes, you're here), but others, like API endpoints (look at UserLocalServiceUtil) are documented and of course it's getting better, in source, in trunk and in every release. For those interested, the whole javadocs story is here https://www.liferay.com/web/olaf.kock/blog/-/blogs/radio-liferay-episode-21-jim-hinkey-bringing-back-javadocs (disclaimer: I'm involved...)